# Re-order media links?

Tags: post-thumbnails, order

I'm trying to re-order the links in the media box when selecting an image. I want to move "Use as featured image" above the insert into post button.

I also want to rename the "Use as featured image" text? I have done this by editing the media.php file in wp-admin/incudes/media.php but I don't want to edit this everytime I upgrade.

Is it possible to re-order the elements without having to re-write the whole function?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Basically I want to move the text above the button and maybe add a label on the left too like the others above. I also want to rename the text "use as featured image".

[image]

EDIT

Thanks to goto10 for helping me get this far, the code below "works" as it changes the text and location of the featured image. Although as I cannot get the attachment ID, it will not save the image...it works by manually typing in the attachment ID.

```
function custom_attachment_fields_to_edit($form_fields, $post) {
    $form_fields['buttons'] = array(
        'label' => 'Banner Image',
        'value' => '',
        'input' => 'html'
    );
    $thumbnail = '';
    $calling_post_id = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['post_id']))
        $calling_post_id = absint($_GET['post_id']);
    elseif (isset($_POST) && count($_POST))
        $calling_post_id = $post->post_parent;

    $attachment_id = ???        

    $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( "set_post_thumbnail-$calling_post_id" );
    $form_fields['buttons']['html'] = $thumbnail = "<a class='' id='wp-post-thumbnail-" . $attachment_id . "' href='#' onclick='WPSetAsThumbnail(\"$attachment_id\", \"$ajax_nonce\");return false;'>Set as Banner Image</a>";

    return  $form_fields;
}

add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'custom_attachment_fields_to_edit', 11, 2);
```

Tried these to get attachment ID :

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $_GET['post_id'] ); 
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $attachment_id = $attachment->ID;
            }
        }

$attachment_id = get_post_meta($_GET['post_id'], '_wp_attachment_image_id', true);
$attachment_id = get_post_meta($_GET['post_id'], '_wp_attachment_url', true );
```

Also tried replacing `$_GET['post_id']` with `$calling_post_id`

Any suggestions on how to get the attachment ID? I tried copying most of the code from `media.php` without any luck.

Comment: Take a look at the filters and actions in the core files you edited. +1 for "not editing core because of upgrades".

Comment: I have used the filter to modify the title of the meta box, although there doesn't seem to be on for the media that I can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Added example of outputting the attachment's id. Assigned it to the variable $attachment_id, since that's how the core code refers to it. Note that the `$post` object (for the attachment) is passed into the callback of the `attachment_fields_to_edit filter`, so you'll have access to all of the attachment's properties.

Yes, this can be done without modifying the core. `attachment_fields_to_edit` is the filter that you need here.

Add this to your functions.php or plugin:

```
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'customize_attachment_fields_to_edit', 11, 2 ); // Note priority 11 to ensure that the customizations are not overridden
    function customize_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ) {
        $form_fields['buttons'] = array(
                'label' => '',
                'value' => '',
                'input' => 'html'
        );
        $attachment_id = $post->ID;
        $form_fields['buttons']['html'] = "<h1>Custom stuff here... Attachment ID: $attachment_id</h1>";

        return  $form_fields;
    }
```

Notes:
The filter `attachment_fields_to_edit` is applied on `line 1147 in \wp-admin\includes\media.php`

Most of the code that sets up the output for the buttons is on `lines 1311-1342 in \wp-admin\includes\media.php`, although there are some variables above `line 1311` that are used to determine how the output is made which are not passed into the `attachment_fields_to_edit filter`.

Essentially, you're going to want to copy the core code and add it to your `customize_attachment_fields_to_edit` callback.  Then format the copied code to suit your needs, but keep in mind that you might need to create some of the vars on your own (`$send`, for example, if you really want to duplicate the core code as close as possible).

Here's a [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-custom-fields-for-attachments-in-wordpress/) to a well written tutorial by Andy Blackwell on customizing WP galleries.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my post, everything upto now works great but am having trouble getting the attachment id.

Comment: No problem, @Elliot. I'm a big fan of being able to customize the built in WP galleries. I edited my answer, adding an example of outputting the attachment's id.

Comment: Doh! Didn't realise how easy it was to get the attachment id. Just one quick question is it possible to do conditional tags in functions.php? Such as if the is_page('1)' : do something? Thanks alot =D

Comment: No prob. Yes, you can use conditional tags in functions.php, but you'd want to do so from within a hook. E.g., 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'customize_content');
function customize_content( $content ) {
 if ( is_page(675) ) {
  return "<h1>--- TEST ---</h1>$content<h1>--- END TEST ---</h1>";
 }
} // See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags